# Beautify Integer values for comparing as strings

Tags: java, string, integer, hql, string-comparison

For some reason I need to enter my integer values to database as string, then I want to run a query on them and compare those integers as strings. Is there any way to beautify integer numbers (between 1 and 1 US billion as an example) so I can compare them as strings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by beautify?

Comment: What do you mean by milliard?  ;-)

Comment: Common term in some European languages (French for sure) for 10^9 - we historically use 10^12 as a billion in Europe.

Comment: sorry for my poor English. I mean numbers from 1 to 1,000,000,000.
Beautify: cast these int values to strings and padding something to them so after this: "1 as a string < 100 as a string" !!!

Comment: Try and be a bit more descriptive about what you want to do. Also, do you mean compare via computer ( a > b) or visually? I only ask since you used the word beautify.

Comment: Please provide some examples of "beautify"

Comment: via computer (a > b). since I want to run a query on these strings, I mean something like this 
Query q = "from A where A.a < ?" + 7.toString()

Answer (score 3):

Just add as much leading zeros as necessary

So the numbers 1,2,3 become in string form: 0000000001, 0000000002, 0000000003
This way string comparison goes correct

In java you'd use:

```
 String.format("%09d", number);
```

to have 9 leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks, I have to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to modify your query to convert the string value back to an integer. (Pseudcode below, may not compile/ work for your database)

```
String sql = " SELECT * "
+ " FROM some_table "
+ " WHERE CAST(some_table.int_column_stored_as_string AS INTEGER) = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInteger(1, myIntValue);
```

One problem with this is that because this runs a function on each row, the database will be unable to use any indices defined on `some_table.int_column_stored_as_string`.